# Rounding Up Our Balance (North America)

Tags: climate

I've been told that if I raise the axial tilt from 23.5 degrees to 25, I'd end up getting hotter summers and colder winters.  That's great, except that Earth's diverse climate makes that statement broad.  So what would the SPECIFIC consequences be?

Since the forum might consider this scenario broad, let's look this over one continent at a time, starting with North America.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Very slight**. As shown in [this interactive axial tilt calculator](http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/007299181x/student_view0/chapter2/seasons_interactive.html), when the globe is set to 25 degrees instead of 23, the average temperature in a country in the northern hemisphere is only slightly hotter in summer (warm.6 instead of warm.5), and slightly colder in winter (cool.4 instead of cool.5). I know, the temperature figures aren't very specific, but I didn't build it. ;)

For reference purposes, imagine the temperature changes as though your city is *"travelling"* north by 1.5 degrees Latitude in winter, and south by 1.5 degrees Latitude in summer.

Comment: So will this apply to the other continents?

Comment: I live around the 45 lat, and did a little looking at what 1.5 degrees is north and south, and the answer is it's only about 100 miles, so we probably wouldn't even notice

Comment: I believe so. Using the axial tilt calculator at extreme angles (or clicking the Venus and Uranus presets), one can see that it is mostly the axial tilt that affects the seasonal temperature extremes, and not necessarily the position on the globe. This makes sense, as it's all about how often your particular location stays in the sunlight. The notable exceptions, of course, are locations closer to (or atop) the poles, which are either (with no tilt) always in sunlight, or (with tilt) outside of sunlight for extended periods of time.

Comment: [Some](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13391) - [related](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2267) - [questions](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4589)... (Also, see the sidebar) >>

Comment: @Ayelis  What sidebar?

Comment: On the right side of the page, while viewing from a desktop computer using a standard internet browser, there are sections that read "Linked" and "Related", which include questions such as 
[What if an Earth-like planet had no axial tilt?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13318)
and [What is the climate of a mountain range at the border of the polar front?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10891).